# One word substitution

Tags: word-choice

The last part of speech

> A. Conclusion 
>   B. Preface
>   C. Epilogue 
>   D. Percussion

**Confused between A and C as both mean same as per Merriam Webster Dictionary** .

Comment: An epilogue is any text that appears at the end of a written work and is  about the preceding material; a conclusion appears at the end but specifically sums up the preceding material.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure I understand the question format, or how fixed your are on using one of the four choices you list.

Frequently the end of a speech is referred to as :

'**closing comments**' , '**closing remarks**' or the speaker may give notice that they're in a finishing stretch by saying '**in-closing**'

I googled up [this discussion at 'reference.com'](https://www.reference.com/education/purpose-closing-remarks-speech-5d0452208edaa404)

> Q: What is the purpose of closing remarks in a speech?
>
> A: QUICK ANSWER
> The closing remarks, or conclusion, of a speech emphasize the primary message that the speaker wants to convey. These final words help the audience remember the main points that were made.

I apologize if suggesting other terms isn't within the scope of the question.

Answer (score 0):

According to **Oxford Advanced Learner's Vocabulary**, the word *conclusion* means, among other things, the end of something:

> 1. At the conclusion of his speech...

The word *epilogue* means a section added at the end of a book, play, film, television program, etc as a comment or conclusion to what has happened in it.

Answer (score 0):

Conclusion doesn't seem to be always the last part of the speech, but mostly does.

In some speech, conclusion can be stated in the head or in the middle of it.